# Find interval of convergence power series $ \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty } \frac{x^n}{\left( 6+(-1)^n \right)^n } $

Tags: calculus, power-series, solution-verification

Find interval of convergence power series $$ \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty }  \frac{x^n}{\left( 6+(-1)^n \right)^n } $$

It is quite easy to show that $$ \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty }  \frac{x^n}{\left( 6+(-1)^n \right)^n } = \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty }  \left( \frac{x}{7} \right)^{2n} + \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty }  \left( \frac{x}{5} \right)^{2n+1} $$

The first series is convergent when $x \in \left( -7,7 \right) $ and second when $x \in \left( -5,5 \right) $. So i suppose that $ \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty }  \frac{x^n}{\left( 6+(-1)^n \right)^n } $ is convergent when $x \in \left( -5,5 \right)  \cap \left( -7,7 \right ) = \left( -5,5 \right)$. Next I have to check convergence in $x=5$ and $x=-5$ (I think it will be quite easy).

Does it work? Or maybe I'm in wrong and my solution is mistaken? (I don't have answer, because it comes from exam).

Comment: Seems like the right intuition. I think you don't have to care about the boundary case when you're asked to find just the radius of convergence.

Comment: As you said, these are only intuition...

Comment: You are absolutely right. If you have two power series with a common center and the radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ ($r_1 \ne r_2$) then the radius of convergence of their sum is $\min(r_1, r_2)$.

Comment: I meant your reasoning is right. I don't know how formal you want your solution to be. What you wrote seems like a proof to me. But if you can use the ["formula"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) for the radius of convergence, then you might want to do that. That's a very straightforward method that doesn't depend on other known results. You need to find $\limsup$ though.

Answer (score 3):

Formally: We are given the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ with $a_n=\frac1{(6+(-1)^n)^n}$. Since $\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac1{6+(-1)^n}$ takes  on $\frac15$ and $\frac 17$ periodically, we calculate
$$ \frac 1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=\max\left\{\frac17,\frac15\right\}$$
and so $R=5$.

---

Your idea is the right intuition, but *in general* the radius of convergence of the sum of two series is not necessarily the minimum of the radii of the summands. It does work, though because the series being added do not "interfere", i.e. each summand has zero coefficients where the other has nonzero ones. (See how this works out to the limsup of the combined sequence being th emax of the summand limsups?)